# disable days before month ago in jquery boostrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm setting up Startdate as month ago today , I'm doing it like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () 
{

}

$("#select_range").click(function () {

    settledates();
});

function settledates() {

    var todaydate = new Date();
    todaydate.setMonth(todaydate.getMonth() - 1);

    var minusmonth = dateFormat(new Date(todaydate), "dd/mm/yyyy");

    $('#startdate').datepicker('update', minusmonth);
}

</script>
```

I'm trying to disable the days before month ago in this datepicker calender.

for that I tried something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () 
{
    var dateToday = new Date();
    dateToday.setMonth(dateToday.getMonth() - 1);        

    $(function() {
        $( "#startdate" ).datepicker({
            minDate: dateToday
        });
    });
}

$("#select_range").click(function () {

    settledates();
});

function settledates() {

    var todaydate = new Date();
    todaydate.setMonth(todaydate.getMonth() - 1);

    var minusmonth = dateFormat(new Date(todaydate), "dd/mm/yyyy");

    $('#startdate').datepicker('update', minusmonth);
}

</script>
```

but this is not disabling the dates before month ago, how to do this properly.

Comment: you want to only allow 30 days before todays date?

Comment: @Akshaypadwal I'm getting the Start date as the date before month ago , what I want is disable the days before that date

Comment: you can try the below edited answer..

Answer (score 0):

**this may be helpful**
*put your starting date in the s eg*

```
 var s = new Date('11-06-2016');
    var befordate = new Date(s.setDate(s.getDate() - 30));

minDate : befordate.getFullYear() +"-"+  (befordate.getMonth()+ 1) +"-"+ befordate.getDate(),
```

Comment: my solution worked for bootstrap datetimepicker does datepicker differ may change functionalities? are you getting any error in console?